# Is there a faster way to iterate over a TreeMap from a specific starting key?

Tags: java, optimization, treemap

I have several TreeMaps. Given some key, something needs to be done with each entry whose key is within some distance of the key in each TreeMap according to some measure specific to that TreeMap. What I currently have uses the lowerKey and higherKey methods repeatedly to find the next key, which is then used to get the entry and update the current key. I tried optimizing this by making iterators that start from the key's position in the TreeMap's entry set
`lower=tree.descendingMap().tailMap(key).entrySet().iterator();`

`higher=tree.tailMap(key).entrySet().iterator();`

This actually took longer. The code that used the iterators instead of lowerKey and higherKey was faster, but creating the iterators in this way took long enough to outweigh that, leading to my question.
Is there a way to iterate through a TreeMap from a specific starting key faster than using lowerKey and higherKey that does not outweigh the speedup with the overhead of creating sub maps?

Comment: What do you mean by "update the current key" You should never update the key of a map. Do you actually mean "change the value associated with the current key"?

Comment: By "update the current key" I did not mean changing any of the keys but rather changing which key represents the current position in the TreeMap. The value associated with a variable is changed, but that variable is not part of the map.

Comment: The creation of those views shouldn’t be too expensive. It’s a bit surprising that it outweighs the iteration savings. Which raises the question whether some context is missing. How large is the map on average? How often do you perform this operation a) on this same map with different keys or b) on different maps.